# Conflict between vectorization/broadcasting and solving an ODE with solve_ivp

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Using a NumPy array and vectorization, I'm trying to create a population of `n` different individuals, with each individual having three properties: `alpha`, `beta`, and `phenotype` (the `phenotype` being calculated as the steady state of a differential equation that involves `alpha` and `beta`). So, I want each individual to have its own phenotype.

However, my code produces the same phenotype for every individual. Moreover, this unwanted behavior only occurs if there happen to be exactly `n` entries in `solve_ivp`'s `y0` array (which here is `[0, 1]`) -- otherwise, a broadcasting error is produced:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,) (3,)
```

Here's the code:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp

def create_population(n):
    """creates a population of n individuals"""
    pop = np.zeros(n, dtype=[('alpha','<f8'),('beta','<f8'),('phenotype','<f8')])
    pop['alpha'] = np.random.randn(n)
    pop['beta'] = np.random.randn(n) + 5
    def phenotype(n):
        """creates the phenotype"""
        def pheno_ode(t_ode, y):
            """defines the ode for the phenotype"""
            dydt = 0.123 - y + pop['alpha'] * (y ** pop['beta'] / (1 + y ** pop['beta']))
            return dydt
        t_end = 1e06
        sol = solve_ivp(pheno_ode, [0, t_end], [0, 1], method='BDF')
        return sol.y[0][-1] # last entry is assumed to be the steady state
    pop['phenotype'] = phenotype(n)
    return pop

popul = create_population(3)
print(popul)
```

In contrast, if the phenotype is calculated from `alpha` and `beta` via a "simple" equation, then vectorization works fine:

```py
def phenotype(n):
    """creates the phenotype"""
    phenotype_simple = 2 * pop['alpha'] + pop['beta']
    return phenotype_simple
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems that I can see:

First, you have the initial condition for the ODE set to `[0, 1]`.  The sets the size of the vector solution for `solve_ivp` to 2, regardless of the value of `n`.  However, the arrays `pop['alpha']` and `pop['beta']` have length `n`, and in your script, you call `create_population` with `n` set to 3.  So you have a mismatch in the array shapes in the formula for `dydt`: `y` has length 2, but `pop['alpha']` and `pop['beta']` have length 3.  That causes the error that you see.

You can fix this by using, say, `np.ones(n)` instead of `[0, 1]` as the initial condition in your call to `solve_ivp`.

The second problem is in the statement `return sol.y[0][-1]` in the function `phenotype(n)`.  `sol.y` has shape `(n, num_points)`, where `num_points` is the number of points computed by `solve_ivp`.  So `sol.y[0]` is just the first component of the solution, and `sol.y[0][-1]` is the last value of the solution for the first component. It is a scalar, so when you execute `pop['phenotype'] = phenotype(n)`, you are assigning the same value (the steady state of the first component) to all the phenotypes.

The return statement should be `return sol.y[:, -1]`. That returns the last *column* of the solution array (i.e. all the steady state phenotypes).

Comment: Thanks, Warren Weckesser, for this great answer!